# Express sum of $(a \cdot b) \bmod n$ as regular matrix product

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic

I'm wondering whether it is possible to express the sum over several multiplications where each multiplication is followed by a modulo operation as a matrix product. More precisely:

I am trying to express
$$
y = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \left[ (a_i \cdot b_i) \bmod n \right]
$$
using transformations of only input and result. Importantly, $n$ can be assumed to be a power of two. I'm wondering whether there exist functions $f, g, h$ that would allow me to remove the modulo operation from the inner sum s.t.
$$
y = f\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \left[ \left(g(a_i) \cdot h(b_i)\right) \right] \right)
$$
The aim is to evaluate this operation using a *regular* matrix product with functions only applied to inputs and outputs.

For the general case, it's possible to express the first equation as
\begin{align*}
y &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \left[ \left[ (a_i \bmod n) \cdot (b_i \bmod n)\right] \bmod n \right]\\
\end{align*}
which I can't simplify further since $(a+b) \bmod n = \left[ (a \bmod n) + (b \bmod n) \right] \bmod n$.

Comment: It seems like you want $y = \left[ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}  (a_i \cdot b_i) \right] \bmod n 
$, but that seems trivial, so I suppose I have not understood the question.

Comment: $$\left[ \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (a_i \cdot b_i) \right] \bmod n \ne  \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left[ (a_i \cdot b_i) \bmod n \right]$$ in the general case (sadly, this follows from the sum over modulo identity at the bottom).

Comment: Are you allowed to take your row and column vectors and separate them into, say, 4 rows and columns each, do four matrix multiplications, then manipulate the 4 sums?

Comment: Not in the context of the original question, as I am trying to calculate said function on top of an existing GeMM implementation.
I am, however, curious, how this would be helpful, assuming it was possible.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\tmod{~\mathrm{mod}~}$What you can do is us use $f=g:x\mapsto x\tmod n$.  Then $g$ maps the input in to some range like $[0,n-1]$ or $[-n/2, n/2-1]$.  The former is sometimes called *unsigned* representation or smallest non-negative representation, and the latter is called *signed* or smallest by absolute value.

What you have to consider is that the range needed to represent the numbers will increase if you don't apply mod in each step of the summation (or don't use modular arithmetic from the start): If $|a_i| < n$, then the sum with its $n$ terms might grow up to $n\cdot (n-1)^2 < n^3$ in the unsigned case.  In the signed case, intermediate values might grow up to $n^3/4$ due to $|a_i|\leqslant n/2$ before you'll apply the final, outer $f$.

As the number of terms in the sum is the same as the modulus, it's unlikely that the range will introduce a problem: With today's common 64-bit integers you can have up to $n=2^{21}$ with unsigned arithmetic and same for signed arith.